# Keeping file name information with Cascalog Tuples

Tags: clojure, cascading, cascalog

I'm looking for a way of keeping a filename that's associated with the tuples/data that originate from that particular file. I've searched around and found that `hfs-wholefile` works really well at getting filenames but it then returns a large chunk of binary information. Is it possible to take this binary information and turn it back into tuples that I can then processes as if I had gotten them from `hfs-textline`?

```
(def file-name-with-data
  "Process a file and associate a filename with it"
   [file]
  (<- [file-name ?data1 ?data2 ?data3 ?data4]
      ((hfs-wholefile file) ?file-name ?binary-data)
      (function-that-im-looking-for ?binary-data :> ?data1 ?data2 ?data3 ?data4)))
```

The example above is ideally what I would like to use to process this information. In Cascalog/Cascading is there a way to turn the bytes into regular variables I can use in queries?

Comment: Hey, this might be better for the mailing list?

Comment: Reposted to usergroup!

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cascalog-user/hfs-wholefile%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false/cascalog-user/qVh4gs2k4i8/vqK75K54ruEJ for the discussion and answers.